# Blender 2.82 EEVEE fire simulation appears in preview but doesn't in final render

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I've got a really annoying problem. The fire simulation is showing perfectly in the preview, however once I render it, it's nothing there. Everything works in cycles, it's just when I switch to EEVEE. Has anyone ran into anything similar? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bloody hell, I've got it, it was behind the glass in the render lol, and in the viewport the glass was switched off. Eeevee works strangely sometimes...